# What does this error mean and how do I fix it? Error: Cannot find module 'html'

Tags: node.js

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. 
Here is the error I am getting when I run node dNode.js

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ricky/LA/dNode.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

Here is what a portion of my code looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var html = require('html');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout: 'main'});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3001);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `var html = require('html');`or run

> npm install html

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is very hard to do try to solve your problem with so little given.
However, based on what you have given you need to specify your view folder and parse the engine to HTML.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```